# Email Contact Form and multiple required fields

Tags: forms, email-contact-form

Based on EE [documentation](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/add-ons/email/contact_form.html#required) to have multiple required fields I need to make the name= attribute an array by using "required[]" but when I do that those fields still are not required (no errors returned).

Form code looks like:

```
        {exp:email:contact_form user_recipients="no" recipients="myemail@domain.com" charset="utf-8"}
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <fieldset id="contact_details">
            <table class="table table-hover">
            <tbody>
            <tr><td>
            <div class="form-group">                
            <label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="company">Company Name <span class="required">*</span></label> 
            <div class="col-md-9"><input type="text" class="input-text required-entry" value="" title="Company Name" id="company" name="required[]"></div>
            </div>
            </td></tr>
            <tr><td>
            <div class="form-group">                
            <label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="fname">First Name <span class="required">*</span></label> 
            <div class="col-md-9"><input type="text" class="input-text required-entry" value="" title="First Name" id="fname" name="required[]"></div>
            </div>
            </td></tr>
            <tr><td>
            <div class="form-group">                
            <label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="name">Last Name <span class="required">*</span></label> 
            <div class="col-md-9"><input type="text" class="input-text required-entry" value="" title="Last Name" id="name" name="required[]"></div>
            </div>
            </td></tr>
            <tr><td>
            <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="address1">Address <span class="required">*</span></label> 
            <div class="col-md-9"><input type="text" class="input-text required-entry" value="" title="Address" id="address1" name="required[]"></div>
            </div>
            </td></tr>
            <tr><td>
            <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="address2">Address 2</label> 
            <div class="col-md-9"><input type="text" class="input-text" value="" title="Address 2" id="address2" name="address2"></div>
            </div>
            </td></tr>
            <tr><td>
            <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="city">City <span class="required">*</span></label>
            <div class="col-md-9"><input type="text" class="input-text required-entry" value="" title="City" id="city" name="required[]"></div>
            </div>
            </td></tr>
            <tr><td>
            <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="state">State/Province <span class="required">*</span></label> 
            <div class="col-md-9">                
                            <select class="required-entry" id="state" name="required[]">
                            <option value="">State/Province</option>
                            <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
                            <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
                            <option value="AZ">Arizona</option>
                            <option value="AR">Arkansas</option>
                            <option value="CA">California</option>
                            <option value="CO">Colorado</option>
                            <option value="CT">Connecticut</option>
                            <option value="DC">District of Columbia</option>
                            <option value="DE">Delaware</option>
                            <option value="FL">Florida</option>
                            <option value="GA">Georgia</option>
                            <option value="HI">Hawaii</option>
                            <option value="ID">Idaho</option>
                            <option value="IL">Illinois</option>
                            <option value="IN">Indiana</option>
                            <option value="IA">Iowa</option>
                            <option value="KS">Kansas</option>
                            <option value="KY">Kentucky</option>
                            <option value="LA">Louisiana</option>
                            <option value="ME">Maine</option>
                            <option value="MD">Maryland</option>
                            <option value="MA">Massachusetts</option>
                            <option value="MI">Michigan</option>
                            <option value="MN">Minnesota</option>
                            <option value="MS">Mississippi</option>
                            <option value="MO">Missouri</option>
                            <option value="MT">Montana</option>
                            <option value="NE">Nebraska</option>
                            <option value="NV">Nevada</option>
                            <option value="NH">New Hampshire</option>
                            <option value="NJ">New Jersey</option>
                            <option value="NM">New Mexico</option>
                            <option value="NY">New York</option>
                            <option value="NC">North Carolina</option>
                            <option value="ND">North Dakota</option>
                            <option value="OH">Ohio</option>
                            <option value="OK">Oklahoma</option>
                            <option value="OR">Oregon</option>
                            <option value="PA">Pennsylvania</option>
                            <option value="RI">Rhode Island</option>
                            <option value="SC">South Carolina</option>
                            <option value="SD">South Dakota</option>
                            <option value="TN">Tennessee</option>
                            <option value="TX">Texas</option>
                            <option value="UT">Utah</option>
                            <option value="VT">Vermont</option>
                            <option value="VA">Virginia</option>
                            <option value="WA">Washington</option>
                            <option value="WV">West Virginia</option>
                            <option value="WI">Wisconsin</option>
                            <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
                            </select>
                   </div>
            </div>
            </td></tr>
            <tr><td>
            <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="zip">Postal Code <span class="required">*</span></label>
            <div class="col-md-9"><input type="text" class="input-text required-entry" value="" title="Postal Code" id="zip" name="required[]"></div>
            </div>
            </td></tr>                
        </tbody>
        </table>
        </fieldset>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-6">
        <fieldset id="contact_details">
        <table class="table table-hover">
        <tbody>            
            <tr><td>
            <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="telephone">Telephone <span class="required">*</span></label>
            <div class="col-md-9"><input type="text" class="input-text required-entry" value="" title="Telephone" id="telephone" name="required[]"></div>
            </div>
            </td></tr>    
            <tr><td>
            <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="telephone2">Telephone (Alternative)</label>
            <div class="col-md-9"> <input type="text" class="input-text" value="" title="Telephone Alternative" id="telephone2" name="telephone2"></div>
            </div>
            </td></tr>    
            <tr><td>
            <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="from">Email <span class="required">*</span></label>
            <div class="col-md-9"><input type="text" class="input-text required-entry validate-email" value="" title="from" id="from" name="from"></div>
            </div>
            </td></tr>    
            <tr><td>
            <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="message">ADD A NOTE <span class="required">*</span></label>
            <div class="col-md-9"><textarea rows="3" cols="5" style="height:150px;" class="input-text" title="Message" id="message" name="message"></textarea></div>
            </div>
            </td></tr>    
        </tbody>
        </table>
        </fieldset>

        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit" style="margin-right:7px;" class="btn btn-block btn-plain pull-right" value="Submit" name="submit">
        </div>

        </div>
        {/exp:email:contact_form}
```

Any clue what is going on? Or maybe I should to use off the shelf extension like Solspace Freeforms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Email Contact Form](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/add-ons/email/contact_form.html#form-fields) doesn't support custom fields other than the defaults of:

- From
- To
- Subject
- Name
- Message
- Captcha

By the looks of your example you're looking to include a lot more than that.

[Solspace Freeform](http://www.solspace.com/software/detail/freeform/) is a popular option but there are other notable options which may be a better fit for your needs including [DevDemon Forms](http://www.devdemon.com/forms/) and [ProForm](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/proform-drag-and-drop-form-builder). They're certainly worth investigating and generally with the power of these addons and the FreeForm being...well...free, the default Email Contact Form is something which I don't see used very often.